# How to keep a table row always the last row?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which shows items, and a row that shows the total of the item prices, and a button to add a row. how to keep the total table always in the bottom

```
<table id="expense-table">
                <tr id="table_main">
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Unit price</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="">Select Item</option>
                            <option value="1">Item 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Item 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" class="unit-price">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" class="quantity">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="total" value="0" disabled>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="total">
                    <td id="total-table" colspan="3">
                        Total
                    </td>
                    <td id="total-result">
                        0
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button id="add-btn">Add Item</button>
```

`addButtonEl.addEventListener("click", addExpenseInput);`

Comment: Use `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and `<tfoot>` for the headings, detail rows, and total row. Append new rows to `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
To ensure the total row always stays at the bottom of your table, even when you add new rows dynamically, you can use JavaScript to insert new rows above the total row rather than appending them to the end of the table. This approach involves selecting the total row and using the insertBefore method to add new rows just before it.

Here's how you could modify your addExpenseInput function to achieve this:

javascript

enter code here
        function addExpenseInput() {
            // Create a new row
            var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
        
            // Add cells and inputs similar to your existing item row
            newRow.innerHTML = `
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="">Select Item</option>
                        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="unit-price">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="quantity">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="total" value="0" disabled>
                </td>
            `;
    
        // Select the total row and the table
        var totalRow = document.getElementById('total');
        var table = document.getElementById('expense-table');
    
        // Insert the new row before the total row
        table.insertBefore(newRow, totalRow);
    }

// Attach the event listener to the Add Item button
var addButtonEl = document.getElementById('add-btn');
addButtonEl.addEventListener("click", addExpenseInput);
This script dynamically creates a new row (<tr>...</tr>) each time the "Add Item" button is clicked. It then inserts this new row into the table right before the total row, ensuring that the total row remains at the bottom. The new row contains the same structure as your template row, with a select for item selection and input fields for unit price, quantity, and total, which is disabled by default.

Remember to incorporate any necessary logic to update the total when item details are changed. This could involve adding event listeners to the newly created input fields to recalculate totals whenever values change.
```